# Conflicto (CONFLICT) al hacer git stash pop

Tags: git

He intentado guardar en el stash el estado actual de trabajo, cambiar a otra rama, hacer un cambio en otra rama, hacer commit de ese otro cambio.
Hasta aquí bien.
Pero cuando intento regresar al estado que había guardado en el stash me da un conflicto.

```
~/t> git stash
Saved working directory and index state WIP on 2: 29f32ca noFuncionaEnvioUDP
HEAD is now at 29f32ca noFuncionaEnvioUDP
~/t> git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
~/t> echo cambiado > envioUDP.cpp
~/t> git add . 
~/t> git commit -m Terminado
[master b340cd7] Terminado
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1237 deletions(-)
~/t> git stash pop
Auto-merging envioUDP.cpp
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in envioUDP.cpp
```

Comment: ¿Cual es el error? Que te de un conflicto es un comportamiento normal...

Comment: @kerunaru Los conflictos se producen al cambiar la misma cosa en dos sitios distintos y luego querer juntarlos .Que no es el caso. No debiera haber conflicto.

Comment: ya hiciste `git mergetool`?

Comment: Pues no. Pero por qué querría usarlo? No quiero hacer un merge, solo quiero volver a como estaba antes de hacer git stash

Comment: Seguramente `git status` te muestra algo así como "unmerged paths", ¿verdad? Sería útil ver toda la salida de este comando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tiene pinta de que has cambiado el mismo archivo tanto en el `stash` como en la rama `master`. Por eso te da conflicto.

Ten presente que el `stash pop` lo que hace es mezclar el estado guardado con la rama actual. Debes volver a `noFuncionaEnvioUDP` antes de hacer el `git stash pop`

Comment: Esto me ha dado la pista que me hacía falta. Mi error es que antes de hacer git stash pop tengo que volver a la rama en que estaba. Si hago git checkout noFuncionaEnvioUDP antes del git stash pop entonces me funciona bien sin conflictos. Si incluyes esto en tu respuesta la puedo dar por buena, aceptarla y votar +1.

Comment: Entiendo que no te encontrabas en la rama correcta entonces, ¿no? **EDIT** Me autocontesto con un sí y edito mi respuesta.